# Distributing persons into cars and autos [from Black Book]

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-distribution

I encountered a very interesting problem from Black Book.

> 14 persons depart from a place in 2 cars of capacity 4 each and 2 auto - rickshaws of capaity 3 each. Find the number of ways in which they can depart if two particular persons insist on going in the same car (internal arrangement is not considered).

The cars and rickshaws are all distinguished.

This seems to be a Grouping and Distribution question.

My attempt:

Segregate the 2 people who insist on going together, and distribute the remaining 12 people in the 2 cars and 2 autos.

Of these 12 people, we know that 3 of them occupy each of the 2 autos, 4 of them occupy 1 car, and 2 of them occupy the other car. Additionally, 2! is added in the denominator to account for the ordering of the autos, to prevent overcounting in the selection.

So, the number of ways to distribute them is:

$$\dfrac{^{12}C_2 \times ^{10}C_3 \times ^{7}C_3 \times \times ^{4}C_4}{2!}$$

Simplifying gives

$$\dfrac{12!}{(3!)^{2}\times 4!\times 2!\times 2!}$$

After this, we account for the 2 people who insisted on going together, by settling them into the car having 2 people. There are $^2C_1$ ways of choosing 1 of the 2 cars having 2 free seats.

Hence, the expression becomes $$\cfrac{12!}{(3!)^{2}\times 4!\times 2!\times 2!}\times ^{2}C_1$$

But the answer given is

$$\cfrac{12!}{(3!)^{2}\times 4!\times 2!\times 2!}\times ^{2}C_1\times 2!$$

Here is my question: Where did the additional 2! come from? Is it because both the auto - rickshaws are identical in the number of people seated? Some input on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear to me which patterns are equivalent.  If we switch the passengers of the two rickshaws, is that a new pattern?  Likewise, are the cars distinguished?

Comment: Yes, that's a new pattern. Also, the cars are distinguishable.

Comment: That should be made explicit in the post.  Also you appear to have something out...you start a paragraph with "But the answer given is..." and then you don't give the official answer.

Comment: Anyway, pick a car for the special couple ($2$ choices)  pick two other people for that car ($\binom {12}{2}$) pick four people for the other car ($\binom {10}4$) pick three for rickshaw $A$ ($\binom 63$) and the rest go to rickshaw $B$. Which doesn't appear to match either of the answers you propose.  Am I still misreading?

Comment: Sorry, silly blunder.  Of course it matches the second solution.

Comment: Alright, I'll make the changes right now.

Comment: @lulu What I've done is basically a scuffed version of what you've done. I just want to know where that extra 2! came from in the solution given.

Comment: In your method, I don't understand the point at which you choose the car for the special couple.  That's why I wrote it out in detail, just to make every choice explicit.  Anyway, I expect that that choice is the missing factor of $2$.

Comment: The 2! multiplied in my final answer, with the numerator is the term for picking the car for the special couple.

Comment: But I don't understand how the selection process is being handled.  Again, that's why I wrote it  out in full detail.  the short hand method is great, but I find that it tends to obscure some of the choices that are being made.

Comment: @lulu I added some adjustments to the question to make it more clear. Check them out! Also, you mentioned you that "it of course matches the second solution". In that case have you deciphered the question and answer? Could you tell me where that additional 2! comes from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find your attempt and the book's difficult to fathom, and suggest that after putting the two "special" people in one of the two cars (in $2$ ways), just form labeled teams of $\,2,4,3,3\,$ people.

thus $\;2\times\Large\frac{12!}{2!4!3!3!}$

Comment: I feel like this is incorrect. As per your answer, if you pick 3 people (say $P_1, P_2, P_3$) for one of the autos, then $P_4, P_5, P_6$  for the other auto, in one of the selection, then in another selection you pick $P_4, P_5, P_6$ for one auto, then  $P_1, P_2, P_3$ for the other auto, they are counted as separate cases but are the same.

Comment: Also, all I want to know is where that additional 2! came from.

Comment: [1] You write, *"The cars and rickshaws are all distinguished."* So ABC in rickshaw 1 and DEF in rickshaw 2 is *different* from DEF in rickshaw 1 and ABC in rickshaw 2. [2] After some time, I shall try to decipher how the book had arrived at its answer (which tallies )

Comment: It seems to me that [1] In your attempt, you started off with an extra $2!$ in the denominator treating the autos as identical, and [2] the book also did the same but corrected it by multiplying by $2$ at the end. [3] I hope the matter is clear now. [4] Lastly, as general advice, *simplest is best*, and you have three options of how you can write the **same** proces, viz. one in the answer I gave, another as $2\times\dbinom{12}2\dbinom{10}4\dbinom63\dbinom33$, and the third as $2\times\dbinom{12}{2,4,3,3}$

Comment: Wow, that's completely true. Thanks for the explanation! +1 and marked as the answer.

Comment: Glad to be of help ! $\;\;$ :)